# Want to extract value of iframe src after user goes from one page to another in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, responsive-design

I am trying to create a page where you can type in a URL and check the pages responsiveness across all devices.

I am doing something extra which can be found on : http://dfcb.github.com/Responsivator/

I want something like this:

I have a master page which has 7 iframes corresponding to each devices portrait and landscape views.

it could be found at http://sentimentanalysis.comeze.com/responsivator/

what I am trying to do e.g. if iframe 1 goes to page A to page B within the iframe I want to goto page B for other 6 iframes as well.

I think it is against same origin policy. I tried exploting onLoad event of iframe but if the src of the iframe changes internally the src using jquery `attr('src')` will not latest value it will give only that src that is set by me in my HTML.

I am not sure how to go about this one. I searched SO but I think there is no easy way to do this. But there has to be some way to do this.

Can anyone suggest any pointer? I would be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried a same-origin URL and your top window's onload handler?  IE, try inputting http://sentimentanalysis.comeze.com/responsivator/img/pattern.png and see if the error console complains or not

Comment: Also, this could be a good read for you concerning IFRAME and ONLOAD http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes#iframe-onload-event